# Is there a way to make the world lighting effect certain object?

Tags: lighting, world

I set the world lighting to really dark, but still visible, because it fits with the environment that i want to portray, but the character themselves is too dark when its rendering, is there a way that i can darken the background without effecting the character? I could use a light source, but I'll have to put a lot of them on different area, even then, some of them didn't light up certain part of the character. Is there anyway i can light up the character like i light up the world?

Comment: hello, have you thought about the Compositor?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your node setup? What objects other than your character are in that scene? If its just the character and an HDRi background for example, there would be a pretty simple node setup for that. If your scene is more complex, the compositor would be the way to go as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Compositor*:

- Create 2 collections, one with the background and its light(s), and perhaps the object so that it drops a shadow on the background, one with the object and its light(s)
- Create 2 view layers, one with the background collection activated but not the object, the other layers will be the opposite:

[image]

[image]

- Don't forget to activate the *Render > Film > Transparent* option:

[image]

- Do a render and in the *Compositor*, enable *Use Nodes* and *Backdrop*, duplicate the *Render Layers* node and at the bottom of these 2 *Render Layers* select the 2 different renders. Mix them through a *Color > Alpha Over*:

[image]